# Example of using Python wtform datetime with sqlalchemy and sqlite

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to create a form using `wtform datetime` that accepts a date with a date picker.

```
form.py
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    eventname = StringField('Event Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    eventstart = DateField(
        'Enter start date and time', id='datepick', validators=[DataRequired()]
     )
```

This renders the date and time picker correctly.  However, I am not understanding how to get it into the correct format using sqlalchemy and sqlite.  It doesn't seem to be validating on submit.  When I add a `print(events)`, the output is `{}`.

```
view.py
@events_blueprint.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():

    form = RegistrationForm()
    print(form.errors)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        event = Events(
            eventname=form.eventname.data,
            eventstart=form.eventstart.data,
            # eventstop=form.eventstop.data,
        )

        db.session.add(event)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Thank you for registering your event.")

    return render_template('add.html', form=form)
```

```
class Events(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'events'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    eventname = db.Column(db.Text(64), unique=True, index=True)
    eventstart = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    #  This is a one-to-many connection with Eventdetails database
    details = db.relationship('Eventdetails', backref='event', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(
        self, eventname, eventstart
    ):
        self.eventname = eventname
        self.eventstart = eventstart


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.eventname}"
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  Ultimately, I would like to factor in the timezone and event end time so I have a time range.

Comment: Add an `else` block to the `if form.validate_on_submit` section and move `print(form.errors)` into the `else` block.  `form.errors` will be empty until the form is validated.

Comment: Thank you, snakecharmerb.  This helped and now I can see the error `{'eventstart': ['This field is required.']}`, however, I have added info to this field.  How do I go about continuing to figure out the issue?

Comment: Assuming it's now validating successfully, can you [edit] the question to include the `Event` model?

Comment: I just updated the events model.  Thank you.